# Show balance column data of previous row in total column in next row for same orderNo in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my table:

```
+------+---------+------+------+
| Name | orderNo  Total   used |
+------+---------+------+------+
| Row1 |    1    |   10 |    2 |
| Row2 |    1    |    8 |    1 |
| Row3 |    1    |    7 |    3 |
| Row4 |    2    |   12 |    8 |
+------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Here what I want:

```
+------+---------+------+------+---------+
| Name | orderNo  Total   used   balance |
+------+---------+------+------+---------+
| Row1 |    1    |   10 |    2 |  8      |
| Row2 |    1    |    8 |    1 |  7      |
| Row3 |    1    |    7 |    3 |  4      |
| Row4 |    2    |   12 |    8 |  4      |
+------+---------+-----+-------+---------+
```

I have calculate the balance from difference of two columns value. but can't set the balance value in next row in total columns.
Can anyone provide me a solution for this?

Comment: What a table!!!

Comment: Can you show us first what you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Go on. Try something. And orderno is irrelevant

Comment: I have solve the difference of two columns, i want to show balance value in new total for next row for same order no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where do you have a problem here

```
SELECT Name, orderNo,  Total ,  used, (Total - used) as balanced
FROM table
```

If you want to add a column which is strongly NOT recommended :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD balanced INT;
```

Then update the table :

```
UPDATE table a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, orderNo, Total, used, (Total - used) AS balanced
            FROM table) b ON b.Name = a.Name AND b.orderNo = a.orderNo
SET a.balanced = b.balanced
```

Comment: I have achieve this but don't know how to use balance 1st row value in next row total for same order no.